# start SQL 2000 server _lost tempdb drive

Tags: sql-server

If the temp db drive is unavailable (others system database files are available), how can I trick SQL server 2000 to create new temp db on C: and start up?

When trying to start up using `sqlservr -c -f -T3608 -T4022` from command prompt, it just displays the following and thats it:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which SQL Server version, including service pack, are you running?

Comment: sql 2000 sp4 8.00.818

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following from a command prompt to run SQL Server in the command prompt.  First, change directories to the SQL server executables folder, (possibly C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Binn).

```
sqlservr -f -s "SQL_INSTANCE"
```

Then, if you want to permanently change the tempdb location, your can run the following SQL:

```
USE master
go
ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = 'C:\<folders>\tempdb.mdf')
go
ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE (NAME = templog, FILENAME = 'C:\<folder>\templog.ldf')
go
```

Stop the SQL Server (control-c) in the command prompt and start the SQL Server service as normal.

Comment: I am trying to use sqlservr -c -f -T3608 -T4022  but it isnt starting up. I know the location of old tempdb files and I have created their directories. SQL has created the temp db files but still it hasn't started up

Comment: I forgot to mention that the command window will show the sqlservr command as running and will not return the command prompt.  Is that what you see?  If yes, have you tried to use SQL Server Management Studio to try to connect to the SQL Server at that point?

Comment: Yes, but the Service is not up :-(

Comment: I guess we can't avoid the error message in the error log then :)  You can start here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319892 for information.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code: you will need to know the logical names of the tempdb database files.  The logical name for each file is in the NAME column

```
USE tempdb
GO
EXEC sp_helpfile
```

Change the location of each file using ALTER DATABASE.

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdb, FILENAME = 'C:\tempdb\tempdb.mdf')
GO
ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdblog,FILENAME = 'C:\tempdb\templog.ldf')
GO
```

Stop and restart SQL Server.

Comment: This works under the assumption that the SQL Service can start.  Without access to the tempdb the database won't be able to start to you can't run T-SQL.

Comment: the fact that it wouldn't start wasn't part of the question when I answered it.

Comment: I am really sorry for the confusion. Appologies...